# ElasticSearch - Aggregation using a sample size

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have an ElasticSearch database that has a large number of records. My data has a numeric `score` and `label`. I am aggregating the median and quartiles of the `score` field for a specific `label`. For example, what is the median score of all documents with the label `foo`.

Does anyone know if it's possible to base those percentile aggregations on a statistically significant sample of the data, instead of the full set, in order to speed up the aggregation query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Term Query or any other query to filter the documents and apply aggregation to those results.
That way the aggression is not applied to all documents only to the query result.

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "field_name": {
        "value": "foo"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "name_example": {
    "avg": {
        "field": "field_name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I was looking to see if there is a way to take a sample of the data after the query by term. I may have millions or billions of records for each label and want to sample those to arrive at a less accurate, but statistically significant median.